# How to pass arguments to function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, call-by-value

I'm working with function pointers in c because I need a callback mechanism for my custom API library.
Summarizing with a simple example:

```
*userfunction*(SY_msg msg)
{
  /* do something */
};
```

The size of **SY_msg** is 1024 bytes.
1024 bytes are therefore in the stack.

A pointer to *userfuncion()* is present as first element in calback_wrapper[].

```
here is an example of use:
// (...) some code
    SY_msg* msg;
    msg = SYmalloc (sizeof(SY_msg)); /* it takes 1024 bytes in heap */
// (...) some code
    calback_wrapper[0] (*msg); /*  1204 are passed by value  */
    /* during userfunction() execution , 1024 unused bytes are present in the heap */
    free (msg); /* now finally heap is free */
// (...) some code
```

But I would like to have the following:

```
// (...) some code
    SY_msg* msg;
    msg = SYmalloc (sizeof(SY_msg)); /* it takes 1024 bytes in heap */
// (...) some code
    memcpy(someplace,msg,sizeof(SY_msg); /*  where "someplace" is a point in the stack referred by the argument of userfunction()  */
    free (msg); /*  heap is free */
    calback_wrapper[0] (*someplace); /* is starts userfunction() execution */
// (...) some code
```

It is possible to find "someplace" address?
My compiler is gcc.

Comment: Why can't you simply leave allocation to the caller?

Comment: `calback_wrapper[0] (*msg); /*  1204 are passed by value  */` Can't you just pass `msg` instead of `*msg` and make the function expect a pointer instead of the whole data structure? As far as I understand it is your own API. You could change it.

Comment: no I can't  because  who will free() msg?

Comment: The Memory management must be invisible to userfunction().

Comment: userfunction() must simply receive the **msg** structure by value,

Comment: This issue seems not to be related to function pointers at all.

Comment: I'm asking if is possible to find the address of the argument of a function , starting from the function pointer.

Comment: How, BTW is `SY_msg` defined? I assumed it to be a `struct`.

Comment: The address of `msg` inside `userfunction()` is `&msg`, which is *not* known by the caller.

Comment: @alk the caller knows the function pointer , which probably has a reference to msg I'm expecting userfunction() + offset = &msg . It depends on the compiler

Comment: This not just depends on the compiler but on its version and the platform.

Answer (score 0):

What keeps from you doing

```
// (...) some code
SY_msg msg, * pmsg;
pmsg = SYmalloc (sizeof(SY_msg)); /* it takes 1024 bytes in heap */
// (...) some code using pmsg instead of msg
memcpy(&msg, pmsg, sizeof(SY_msg)); /*  where "someplace" is a point in the stack referred by the argument of userfunction()  */
free (pmsg); /*  heap is free */
calback_wrapper[0] (msg); /* is starts userfunction() execution */
// (...) some code
```

in the above example you can replace

```
memcpy(&msg, pmsg, sizeof(SY_msg));
```

by

```
msg = *pmsg;
```

Comment: msg = 1024 bytes in stack

Comment: userfunction = 1024 bytes in stack

Comment: pmsg = 1024 bytes in heap

Comment: @Giorgio: You define the user-function to allocate 1024 bytes on the stack:  `userfunction(SY_msg msg)`. If you do not want this, define it differently.

Comment: Im looking for a clever way  to save space in the stack. The optimal solution could be 1024 bytes in heap and 1024 bytes in the stack from the _userfunction()_.

Comment: @Giorgio: "*1024 bytes in heap and 1024 bytes in the stack from the userfunction()*" that is what your 1st snippet exactly does.

Comment: I see your point. No way. To pass a  `SY_msg` by value it needs to be dereferenced and with this allocated on the caller side to actually do the call.

Comment: Yes it does , but in that case  free (msg) will be executed only  after the return of userfuncion() . This code is intended as part of a task of a RTOS.

Comment: If `userfunction()` is a long runner you could introduce some asynchronism here by. Would using threads be an option?

Answer (score 0):

There are wrong assumptions in my question.
The argument of user function() is allocated in the stack just AFTER the function call.
Maybe some kind of "contextswich" could solve this problem.
Example:

- Call userfunction();
- "contextswich"
- Free the heap
- "contextswich"
- Resume userfunction();

But in any case, an assembly code snippets is requested.